# Alinhar vertical dando erro!

Tags: css, css3

como faço para que a imagem e o link abaixo fiquem alinhados ao centro verticalmente?

A imagem e o link em linha, e essa linha, alinhada verticalmente ao centro (middle) em relação à div login

Tentei de 2 formas:

1)

```
      .login {
          display: block;
          width: 100%;
          height:50px;
          border:#E9E9E9 3px solid;
          position:relative;
      }

      .login img, .login a {
          display:inline-block;
          vertical-align:middle;
      }

</style>

    <div class="login">
       <img src="_img/_iconesLoja/email.png" />&nbsp;<a href="minhaConta.php">Minha Conta</a>
    </div>
```

2)

```
<style>  
  .login {
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
      height:50px;
      border:#E9E9E9 3px solid;
      position:relative;
  }
  .login .lg {   
      display: block; 
      vertical-align:middle;
      height:30px;
  }
  .login .lg img, .login .lg a {
      display:inline-block;
      vertical-align:middle;
  }
</style>

<div class="login">
  <div class="lg">
    <img src="_img/_iconesLoja/email.png" />&nbsp;<a href="minhaConta.php">Minha Conta</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Nenhum dos 2 deu certo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Então se faz um mix usando a propriedade `text-align:center` e `line-hegiht`.

```html
<style>  

      .login {
          display: block;
          width: 100%;
          height:50px;
          border:#E9E9E9 3px solid;
          position:relative;
          text-align:center;
      }

      .login img, .login a {
          display:inline-block;
          vertical-align:middle;
          line-height:50px;      
      }

</style>

    <div class="login">
       <img src="_img/_iconesLoja/email.png" />&nbsp;<a href="minhaConta.php">Minha Conta</a>
    </div>
```

Comment: O alinhamento que preciso é vertical

Comment: Você diz a imagem em cima do link como na resposta acima ou dessa forma mas no centro vertical da div ?@CarlosRocha

Comment: imagem e link lado a lado, e centralizados verticalmente ao middle para que o link não fique em cima em relação à imagem. E, esse bloco que contem a imagem e o link alinhados verticalmente ao middle em relação à div login

Comment: Ve-lá man @CarlosRocha editei...

Comment: era isso mesmo, só pode tirar o text-align: center pois isso não vou usar!

Answer (score 2):

Neste caso você irá precisar alterar via `line-height`. Como no exemplo abaixo:

```css
.login {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  border: #E9E9E9 3px solid;
  position: relative;
}

.login img,
.login a {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 3rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="login">
  <img height="40" src="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-1CHUH2gG8xE/VNSwMQHnVOI/AAAAAAAAAiM/4_XE0KblWs4/s1600/Twitter.png" />&nbsp;<a href="minhaConta.php">Minha Conta</a>
</div>
```

Não há uma forma automática de realizar este processo a não ser que você mude para `flex`. Que por sua vez seria assim:

```css
.login {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  border: #E9E9E9 3px solid;
  position: relative;
  align-items: center;
}

.login img,
.login a {
  display: flex;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="login">
  <img height="40" src="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-1CHUH2gG8xE/VNSwMQHnVOI/AAAAAAAAAiM/4_XE0KblWs4/s1600/Twitter.png" />&nbsp;<a href="minhaConta.php">Minha Conta</a>
</div>
```

**EDIT: Explicação Vertical-Align**

- Elementos `inline` ou `inline-block` (somente) podem ser alinhados
  verticalmente usando o vertical-align: middle. Porém isso não incluí
  o alinhamento da div parente. Isso alinha somente com as linhas em
  que ele pertence. Como exemplificado nesse
  [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jBthq/).
- Para elementos `block`, o alinhamento é mais complicado e vai
  depender bastante da situação:

  - Se o elemento tiver uma **altura fixa**, você pode usar a posição
    `absolute`e ajustar a sua `height`, `margin-top`, e a `top`. Exemplo: 
    [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YFncP/2/)
  - Se o elemento que você deseja centralizar for simples, você também
    pode ajustar a sua `line-height` até que ele fique ajustado a
    `height` do elemento pai. É uma forma bem versátil de se utilizar.
    Exemplo: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d4zGF/).
  - E ainda há muitos outros casos especiais...

Comment: Por favor, me explique quando é que usamos vertical-align? Porque sempre que preciso usar não funciona!

Comment: @CarlosRocha checa por favor a minha edição de Explicação.

Comment: Entendi, tem inline ou inline-block, usa vertical-align naturalmente. Display Block, precisa tratar o position

Comment: @CarlosRocha É por aí. Mas a forma mais eficaz de se fazer o que você quer, na minha opinião, seria tentar compreender o `flex`.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar a propriedade `display: flex` para facilitar o alinhamento, veja:

```
.login {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center; // Alinha ao centro horizontalmente
    align-items: center; // Alinha ao centro verticalmente
    flex-direction: column; // Define que um elemento tem que estar sempre um abaixo do outro e não ao lado.

    border: 3px solid #E9E9E9;
}


<div class="login">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" />&nbsp;<a href="minhaConta.php">Minha Conta</a>
</div>
```

- Veja funcionando no [codepen](http://codepen.io/rafa-acioly/pen/ryeOmE)
- Saiba [mais sobre flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)